# How to prove that $\frac{3n^2-5}{7n^3+2n+1}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm studying for an analysis I exam and one type of question is proving that a sequence converges. My first attempt is to split it up into the sequences $\frac{3n^2}{7n^3+2n+1}$ and $\frac{5}{7n^3+2n+1}$ and the second one goes to zero, so I only have to work with the first one. I tried proving that it is monotonic and bounded but I can't get the monotony to work. Am I missing something obvious? Is there a better way?

Comment: You're working too hard when the $\epsilon,N$ formulation works just fine. Notice that $$\frac{3n^2-5}{7n^3+2n+1} < \frac{3n^2}{7n^3} < \frac{1}{n}$$ with $n > N = \frac{1}{\epsilon}$. This concludes the proof without any theorems, just from first principles.

Comment: Try squeezing it... for $n \ge 2$, say, you have $(3n^2 - 5)/(7n^3 + 2n + 1) > 0$ and $< 3/(7n)$, where the latter sequence goes to zero; so it converges to zero.

Comment: When working with quotients of polynomials, just divide numerator and denominator by the maximum degree monomial. Then you will easily see the convergence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If $n\in\mathbb N$, $3n^2-5<3n^2$ and $7n^3+2n+1>7n^3$. So,
$$
\frac{3n^2-5}{7n^3+2n+1}<\frac{3n^2}{7n^3}=\frac{3}{7n}.
$$
Since, $\frac{3n^2-5}{7n^3+2n+1}>0$ if $n>2$, and since $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3}{7n}=0$, the squeeze theorem implies that
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{3n^2-5}{7n^3+2n+1}=0.
$$